# Can't shrink my SQL Server 2008 Log files - 260GB currently

Tags: sql-server-2008

My database log files have grown to 260GB and I need to shrink them. I have tried numerous scripts such as:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE ('HM_Log', 0)
```

As well as using the Shrink option in SQL Server Management Studio however the log file doesn't seem to shrink.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

The database is on my production server and actively used, I also have a maintenance plan setup to run all the relevant tasks including a daily transaction log backup and a weekly full backup which appears to be working fine.

I need to shrink it down so I can do a full backup + restore on my local development machine, however at the moment the log files is too large for my local drive.

Comment: Not in any way programming-related --> please post on dba.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com instead

Comment: @marc_s - would be more useful for you to flag for a mod to migrate rather than suggest to the user he ask somewhere else. Otherwise OP just cross posts (as has happened in this case: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/sql-server-2008-log-file-out-of-control-cant-shrink-it).

Comment: @Kev: I'll try to remember - too bad you cannot select "belongs on dba.se" from the "close - off-topic" options..... it's such a frequent case.....

Comment: @marc_s - trust me, there are some very good reasons why there isn't :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to backup the log file, then it *should* be reduced in size automatically.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178037.aspx

In particular, this bit:

Typically, truncation occurs automatically under the simple recovery model when database is backed up and under the full recovery model when the transaction log is backed up. However, truncation can be delayed by a number of factors. For more information, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345414.aspx.